# Specific events in sublime text 3

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext3

I am writing a plugin for Sublime Text 3 such that I need to do either of two things:

1) Run a function every 300 milliseconds
2) Run a function whenever the cursor changes position

Although I have been looking over the documentation and examining the examples in the `Default` package, I yet am having trouble achieving my goal. What would help me is small example that prints "hello, world" to a buffer every time one of the above 2 conditions are met. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an answer I gave to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22063366/show-info-about-current-character-in-status-bar-in-sublime-text-2) it has something similar, you also add set_timeout for running every 300ms:

**annoying_helloworld.py**

```
class someclass():
    def run(x):
        print("Hello world!" + str(x))

    def run_with_timeout(x):
        someclass.run(x)
        sublime.set_timeout(lambda: someclass.run_with_timeout(123), 300)

class utfcodeCommand(sublime_plugin.EventListener):
    def on_selection_modified(self, view):
        someclass.run(666)

sublime.set_timeout(lambda: someclass.run_with_timeout(123), 300)
```